# How to compare two contours? (font comparison)

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm trying to analyse two contours and give a percent corresponding to their similarity. Assuming I have all the point's coordinates describing these contours (just like an SVG path), based on which factor should I tell they're almost identical ?

After some Google searches, I found something related to Fourier descriptors, are they relevant for my case ?

---

### Edit

What I want to do is to compare several fonts to another one. Just like would do [What the font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), but not with an image. Thanks to the produced algorithm, it would be possible to find a font equivalent according to the similarity percentage.

Some scripts just compare the bounding box for each letters, but it's not enough. I need a way to tell that Arial is closest to Verdana than to Webdings. So assuming I can extract the contour from the fonts, I need a way to compare two contours.

For example (with "logical" percent values):

[image: Font comparison, the bold G is the closest]

Comment: This problem is harder than it seems, I wouldn't be surprised if you receive no answers. The biggest problem is what is similarity. Similar shape? Squared sum of vertex distances? Or what? You have to formulate the question well by yourself, we cannot do it for you.

Comment: I'm talking about similar shapes. A rectangle is more similar to a square than a circle is. Actually I don't know any "common way" to express the percentage, so I'm wondering if there is any comparison algorithm for shapes.

Comment: You should tell us what application you have in mind because there is no general answer to your question. You should be more specific about what you want.

Comment: Edited as requested. Tell me if you need more informations.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. Essentially what you're talking about is looking at the font letter from a flat perspective and essentially using the grayscaled color as the z coordinate thus (because of font shading around the edges) creating a sort of bump-map. Then based upon this trying to correlate the shape of the contour maps between letters of differing fonts, correct?  I dont beleive this exact thing has been done, but I do have quite a few ideas for you.

Comment: @trumpetlicks: I'm not sure if I understood your bump-map thing right,  but [is this what you're talking about](http://s14.postimage.org/odxvi5x7l/Stack_Overflow_Font_comparison_bumpmap.png) ? If the `bw_original` - `bw_current` is approximately the line `y = 0`, then `original` and `current` are almost the same. Is that acceptable for any case ?

Comment: Thats not exactly what I was thinking.  There are already 2 dimensions to a font letter, it has a width and height.  Where it is invisible and where it is not, can be viewed on the Z axis.  That Z axis can or may not be binary (black or white), and indeed could be shades of gray.  This is what sets up your 3D surface plot (or what i was originally refering to as bump-map).  From there we could perform quite a bit of math to find out a lot about a font.  You could analyze a letter for it's derivatives at each point, and correlate vectors, etc... there is tons you could do!!!

Comment: This could then turn into creating 3D parametric curves that define the font so that you could then compare fonts by their true mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two basic ways to approach the general problem (font matching): symbolic and statistical.  a good solution will probably combine both in some way.

a symbolic approach uses your knowledge of the problem in a direct way.  for example, you can make a list of the things you (as an intelligent human) would use to characterise fonts.  the kind of questions that [identifont](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html) uses.  this approach means writing routines that are smart enough to detect the various properties (eg stroke width, whether certain loops are closed, existence of serifs, etc) plus a decision tree (or "rule engine") that puts the yes/no/unsure answers together and comes up with an answer.

the statistical approach sounds more like what you were thinking about, and is probably how what the font works.  here the idea is to find some general properties and use those as weights to find a "best" selection.  for example, if you have lots of fonts then you can train a neural net (input being pixels at some sample resolution).  there you don't need to know "how" the net decides - just that given enough training data it will find a way to do so.  or you could just look at the sum of all the dark pixels - that would likely give you results similar to your percentages above.

this sounds simple, but often it's not so easy to find simple statistical measurements that show differences well in all the ways you want.

so then there's a large middle ground between the two.  the idea being that if you can pull in some of the ideas from the first group then you can make the approaches in the second much more efficient.  while the simplest neural net approach is "all in one" (it includes the calculations and the decisions) you can separate those out.  so instead of just giving the net a bunch of pixels you can give it more "meaningful" inputs - things that you know help detect between different fonts.  things like stroke width, or the number of "holes" in the character.  you can also add some smarts to remove things that might otherwise confuse results - for example, pre-scaling to the same height (if you have a full font set then you can scale everything so that the height of a lowercase "m", say, is constant).

fourier descriptors are a way of characterising the "outside shape" of something and so could be used as an input to a statistical approach as i've described above.  in the example you give the fourier descriptors will pick up the "spikiness" of the serifs in the lower G, and so would indicate that it is very different from the G on the left.  but they care much less about stroke width and nothing at all about scale (magnification/zoom) (which can be a good or bad thing - if you're being given random letters of different sizes, you don't want to be sensitive to size, but if you've normalized to a standard "m" for an entire alphabet then you certainly do want to include that).  since the output is just a spectrum you can compare different letters by cross-correlation of use something like PCA to categorize different types of letter.

other ideas would be 2d cross-correlation (the maximum of the normalised correlation gives you some idea of how similar two things are) or simply seeing what fraction of pixels are common in both letters.

as the comments say, this is a huge problem (and i am not an expert - the above is just random bullshit from being an interested bystander).

but, to finally answer your question, if what you have is an outline, then a fourier descriptor would be a good place to start.  since that focuses on shape rather than "weight" i would combine that with something like total area enclosed by the outline.  then write some code to calculate those and see what numbers you get for some example alphabets.  if it seems to distinguish some letters, but not others, then look for some other measurements that would help in those cases.  you will likely end up combining quite a few approaches to get something both fast and reliable.

alternatively, if you just want something simple, try using some easy-to-measure values like height, width, total number of pixels "inside" the contours, how many strokes you cross along vertical or horizontal lines, etc.  combining a bunch of those could get you something "good enough" for some purposes, if you aren't comfortable with the maths involved in fourier transforms etc.

Comment: Many good ideas in this answer. Thanks ! I'll edit my post when I finish this project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a neural network based approach? [This](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFsQFjAB&url=http://www.ecpe.nu.ac.th/paisarn/Puplications/MMSP01.pdf&ei=_xfOT5jtDsnbtAbKwvDUCg&usg=AFQjCNHWz5iBAOtzjR87IwZ7l8TfvUxi8Q) paper uses a Self-Organizing Tree map to perform content based image retrieval. With a good training set, it should be possible to create a multilayer network (or [SOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-organizing_map)) that can give you an accurate similarity measure.